# installing connectors for confluent cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-mq, confluent-cloud

I'm trying to install MQ source & sink connectors for our confluent cloud. I've done this for on-prem apache kafka but doing the same of cloud seems to be different. Following the confluent documents says I need to have a platform installed on my local, which I did, and then to run a confluent-hub install which does install the connector on my local and then use the json for distributed instance.
My problem is when I run the json, it says the class for mq was not found, I tried to point the CLASSPATH to the dir where the jars are but still get the same error. How do I run this successfully?

```
--
ERROR Uncaught exception in REST call to /connectors (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper:61)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.ibm.mq.IbmMQSourceConnector,
```

Also want to understand how installing connector on local would apply to my cloud cluster? Not sure what I'm missing!

Answer (score 1):

Confluent Cloud doesn't support custom connector installation, last I checked. They need to explicitly support and offer it.

I assume you're reading some documentation that indicates you need to run your own Connect cluster (not necessarily locally), where you have full control over the connectors that are installed

Comment: This is confluent developed connector "Kafka Connect IBM MQ Source", their document shows I'm supposed install it with confluent-hub and then connect with a platform instance. Cant this be done unless they explicitly assign this connector to us?

Comment: "Developed" doesn't mean "offered by Confluent Cloud". So no, those instructions are all for your own instances of Kafka Connect installation, i.e. Confluent themselves would run those commands in the Confluent Cloud cluster for all clients using it